# VBA loop group of buttons on UserForm

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I have a user form with a group of radio buttons. O when I click the continue button I want it to iterate over each button.

I would have thought there would be something I could do with a for loop, like 'For Each button In group'!

Is there a way to do this?

edit***********

I have decided to push the buttons into arrays and loop through the array.  I found this was more suitable as it allowed access to all the OptionButton properties where-as looping through Controls did not.

If there is a better way to do this I'd still like to know.  What I wanted to do in Doug's answer below was:

```
'... within For Each Loop
    If cCont.GroupName = "GroupB" Then
        'blah blah blah
    End If
```

This didn't work as GroupName was not available on cCont which was declared as "Control".

Thanks again for the replies!

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do this. Can you edit the question with the code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
            Dim cCont As Control

            For Each cCont In Me.Controls
                If TypeName(cCont) = "CommandButton" Or TypeName(cCont) = "OptionButton" Then
                    cCont.Caption = "Boobaloobie"
                End If
            Next cCont
```

Alright this is exactly what you're looking for. Works for me perfectly

Comment: "Control" is key! This is what I have been looking for! I have been searching for GroupName etc and found nothing! I guess I could throw in an 'And' to the condition to check if the GroupName matches too right?

Comment: it seems like youre well on your way to solving it :)

Comment: I'm very new to using userForms (if you couldn't guess) and I thought I was well one my way to solving it but it seems otherwise.  
If I declare cCont As "Control" I cannot acccess the GroupName property.  
If I declare cCont As "OptionButton" (as this is all I want to check for) then it gives a type mis-match in my For Loop when trying to loop through Me.Controls.
I'm not trying to get you to tell me exactly what to do but I need some direction?!

Comment: to further explain.  I have two groups of OptionButtons, hence me needing to check what group it is part of.  I can work around it for now simply by counting through the OptionButtons (so say after 4 - the first group of buttons - I know I'm on the next group) but this seems a long approach to what I need to do.

Comment: Cheers Doug.  Strange!  Maybe it's certain Controls that aren't working then, I must have been iterating past one that didn't support the GroupName property as I have just copied and pasted your code and chaged the Boobaloobie bit for `MsgBox(cCont.GroupName)` and it works until it gets to a component that doesn't have a GroupName property.  Thanks for your help!  I will try this again as it seems much more efficient for what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I searched google for "vba userform get controls", this is the top result:

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/control-loop.htm

```
Dim control As Control
For Each control In Me.Controls

    If TypeName( control ) = "RadioButton" Then

        ' do stuff
    End If

Next
```

Comment: beat you to it :P

Comment: @Dai thanks for the answer btw, I had to mark Doug as correct as he was first in there.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add a suffix to the control’s name that symbolized the group it was in. 
Then it was a simple matter of looping through and checking for the suffix text.